# Prepend scalar and arrays to another array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, types

I am working on a set of C functions that will allow for dynamically growing arrays of the user definition.  I have been able, with the help of some on this site to develop functions that act as an array initialize,and another function that can append a scalar to the array or append an array to the array.  I am using a struct titled `Array` which acts as a container for the array `array`, the active length of the array `len`, the total allocated size of the array `size`, and the memory per indice `elem`.

The first function `initialize_array` allocates the memory and initializes the array, and the function `init_array` is a wrapper for `initialize_array` that pre-formats some information and returns an `Array` data type.  Finally I have a function `append_array` that can take a scalar or an array and can append the array within the `Array` struct using a `memcp` method that is cast to a `char` to assist in pointer arithmetic. I am trying to recreate the `append_array` function with a `prepend_array` function that will add the scalar or array passed in `*items` in the very first indices and push the other indices to the left.  I am a bit lost on how to do this, any suggestions would be helpful.

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    void *array; // Container for array
    size_t len;  // Active length of array
    size_t size; // Size of allocated memory
    int elem;    // Memory consumption per element
} Array;

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices);
Array init_array(int size, size_t num_indices);
int append_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count);
int prepend_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count);

#endif /* ARRAY_H */
```

array.c

```
#include "array.h"

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices) {
    void *pointer;

    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem);

    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        array->size = num_indices;
    }
}

Array init_array(int size, size_t num_indices) {
    Array array;
    array.elem = size;
    initiate_array(&array, num_indices);
    return array;
}

int append_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count) {
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    memcpy((char *)array->array + array->len * array->elem, items, count * array->elem);
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}

int prepend_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count) {
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    // Not sure how to handle this with memcp like was used for append_array
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j;
    float ii = 0.0;
    size_t indices = 20;
    Array float_test = init_array(sizeof(float), indices);
    Array int_test = init_array(sizeof(int), indices);
    // Populate both arrays
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        ii += 1.1;
        append_array(&int_test, &i, 1);
        append_array(&float_test, &ii, 1);
    }

    int a[3] = {10, 9, 8};
    prepend_array(&int_test, a, 3);
    // Print int array values
    for (i = 0; i < int_test.len; i++)
    {
        printf("Value: %d Size:%zu \n",((int *) int_test.array)[i], int_test.len);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: regarding: `if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);`  Since `pointer` contains `NULL` passing `pointer` to `free()` has no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prepend elements to the array, after allocating additional memory, you'll first need to *move* the existing elements.

When the *destination* and *source* memory has the possibility of overlapping, we use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) to safely move our data around<sup>1</sup>.

After moving our existing elements, we then copy the new elements into place.

Visualized:

```
A is [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
V is [99, 88, 77]

resize(A):      [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, __, __, __]
move(A + 3, A): [__, __, __, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
copy(A, V):     [99, 88, 77, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
```

Based on your code, this would look something like:

```
memmove(
    ((char *) array->array) + count * array->elem,
    array->array,
    array->len * array->elem);

memcpy(array->array, items, count * array->elem);
```

---

<sup>1.</sup> The use of [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy to and from overlapping memory is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), and a source of many bugs.